# PHP sort array of associative arrays by element size / string size

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Is there a way to sort an array of associative arrays by the length of one of the elements?  What I am trying to do is order the arrays by the largest to smallest description length.

```
$some_array = [];
$some_array[0] = ['name'=>'a name','description'=>'a description'];
$some_array[1] = ['name'=>'a name1','description'=>'a description 1'];
$some_array[2] = ['name'=>'a name2','description'=>'a description two for the third array element'];
$some_array[3] = ['name'=>'a name3','description'=>'a description three'];
```

With the above example `$some_array[2]` should come first followed by `3` then `1` then `0`.

Comment: Use [usort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Comment: `usort($some_array, function($a, $b) { return (strlen($a['description'] > strlen($b['description']) ? 1 : -1; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP >= 5.5.0 needed for `array_column`:

```
array_multisort(array_map('strlen', array_column($some_array, 'description')),
                SORT_DESC,
                $some_array);
```

Comment: fyi: [github.com/ramsey/array_column: Provides functionality for array_column() to projects using PHP earlier than version 5.5](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column). nice answer btw.

Answer (score 2):

Use `usort`to sort arrays based on custom parameters.

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return strlen($b['description']) - strlen($a['description']);
});
var_dump($array)
```

Comment: Correct, but its probably more readable using the `<` or `>` operators.